# Strategies for predicting values of a time-dependent CDF, given covariates

Tags: time-series, modeling, survival, ordinal-data, cumulative-distribution-function

I've got data that looks like this:

```
   id month  progress           x1 x2
1   1     1 0.0000000 -1.292681937  A
2   1     2 0.0000000  0.148379515  D
3   1     3 0.0000000 -0.377641741  C
4   1     4 0.0000000 -1.733460409  B
5   1     5 0.1368025 -2.536271182  C
6   1     6 0.3729237  0.246897737  D
7   1     7 1.0000000 -1.486625810  A
8   1     8 1.0000000  0.762212659  E
9   1     9 1.0000000  0.139405785  A
10  1    10 1.0000000 -0.199510442  B
11  1    11 1.0000000  0.023842425  C
12  1    12 1.0000000 -1.498720539  D
13  2     1 0.0000000 -0.448647036  C
14  2     2 0.0000000  1.152180009  B
15  2     3 0.1299298 -0.753947848  E
16  2     4 0.5229756  0.338629784  B
17  2     5 0.7506691  0.540268370  D
18  2     6 1.0000000  0.766976334  D
19  2     7 1.0000000  0.927866060  D
20  2     8 1.0000000  0.311370647  A
21  2     9 1.0000000 -0.118382759  A
22  2    10 1.0000000 -1.275606521  A
23  2    11 1.0000000 -1.274525301  D
24  2    12 1.0000000 -0.002151246  C
25  3     1 0.0000000  0.249371755  B
26  3     2 0.0000000  0.820863808  E
27  3     3 0.2492407  1.054430344  E
28  3     4 0.6452163 -0.734227013  E
29  3     5 0.8568588  0.613731243  A
30  3     6 1.0000000  0.129128763  C
31  3     7 1.0000000 -0.651546878  D
32  3     8 1.0000000  1.529601850  C
33  3     9 1.0000000 -0.101137325  A
34  3    10 1.0000000 -0.049928413  E
35  3    11 1.0000000 -0.114480189  B
36  3    12 1.0000000 -0.431910505  C
```

[image]

Given a training set with a label of `progress` features `x1` and `x2`, I want to predict whole sequences of `progress` in new data where I don't observe it, but where I do have `x1` and `x2`.  I'm not entirely sure what the best way to go about this is -- nothing seems perfect.  Here's what I've considered so far:

1. Survival models.  These have the advantage of explicitly modeling the time until `progress` crosses some threshold.  But survival models have the drawback of having no straightforward way of encoding my pre-event data.  So, say I know that `progress` gets to `1` in month `8`, and that the value of `progress` for month `7` is `.56`.  Survival models would have me put `8` as the DV.  Maybe I could just use lags of the DV, as well as lags of all of the covariates?

That's another problem with survival models:  if I put in a lot of lags, I'll (a) get a lot of covariates and need model selection, and (b) will start to get `NA` values because of the heterogeneity in start time.

Finally, the predictions would all be in terms of probabilities of reaching 1.  Really my outcome isn't that -- it's a proportion completed.  There may be cases where the two phenomena follow quite different processes.

So survival models aren't straightforward.

2. Ordinal logistic regression.  I know that I can put proportion data into a basic `glm` in R, but the `polr` function in `MASS` is old and janky, and can't handle non-factor outcomes.  I could think about hand-coding something, but that doesn't seem worthwhile.
3. Model the first difference of progress, perhaps using a tweedie GAM or the zero values pre-and post-growth.  I'd need lags of the DV to deal with the fact that change will depend on levels.  This has the drawback that there is nothing to enforce predictions of the overall curve falling between zero and 1.
4. Parametric approximation:  fit the closest gaussian mean and variance to the CDFs that I have, and model those.  This is probably the easiest, but the parametric approximation will be really coarse given that this is monthly data.

None of these are great.  Suggestions?

Comment: It seems pretty irrelevant to "survival". Your graph shows you already have estimates of survival from the data. (Although you haven't labeled your graph well, as we have no idea what the colors mean). Why can't you just hot-deck the survival function to new observations? (match the x1, x2 to be predicted to the closest x1, x2 with a prediction)

Comment: @AdamO first off the data are fake.  I've got a few dozen x's IRL.  Second, the point is that I've got a lot of data where I don't observe `progress` over any of the 12 periods, and I want the conditional expectation of it for every month, given the values of covariates.  This'd be trivial if all my data was labeled.

Comment: Estimating the survival function is a separate task. Lots of posts on it elsewhere. No reason not to use a step function, a linear interpolation, some kind of nonlinear least squares, or maximum likelihood.

Comment: @AdamO linear interpolation doesn't make any sense when the outcome is never observed, only the covariates.  Parametric approaches only make sense when the parametric structure is known or approximated.  I'm actually using the normal cdf (option 4) as a sort of temporary hack, though I'd prefer something more nonparametric.  Basically I'm setting the mean and variance of these curves as a function of the covariates and estimating that function.  NLLS isn't obvious, given the cumulative nature of the data, if it makes any sense at all.

Comment: I can't divinate what the context is, you have a variable called "progress" that goes from 0 to 1. Parametric structure is never known, we often make reasonable guesses, just as you have done using a normal CDF as a "hack" as you call it. You should revise the question and focus less on  posting the data and graphs and more on describing what you have and your objective.

Comment: @AdamO I'm sorry that you don't like my question, but I'm pretty sure that it isn't as vague as you say.  It's simple really:  say you had 12 month's worth of `x1` and `x2`, and you wanted to predict `progress` for each month.  How would you do it if you also had a bunch of labeled observations for training?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93679/discussion-between-adamo-and-generic-user).